# Searching character on strings

Tags: c++, string, search, character

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string id;

    cout << "Enter your ID: ";
    getline(cin, id);

    for(char i = 'A'; i <= 'z'; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= id.length(); j++) {
            if(id[j] == id.find(i)) cout << "It has characters.";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to enter an id number, but it must to be an integer. If the id has any character it should return a message. But I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: `for(char i = 'A'; i <= 'z'; i++)` seems to be wrong. Difference in A and a is 32 and 26.

Comment: So do you want to search for characters, or do you want to make sure a string contains only digits? These two are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
if !std::all_of(id.begin(), id.end(), std::isdigit)
```

since he said that "it must to be an integer"?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems: The first is that [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) doesn't return a character, it returns a *position*. The second problem is that your inner loop will loop out of bounds for the string.

Also note that in the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) alphabet, there are special characters between the upper- and lower-case letters.

Comment: I think that i solved it:
for(char i = 'A'; i <= 'z'; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <= id.length(); j++){
        if(id[j] == i) cout << "It has characters." << endl;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

If the id must be an integer it is better to verify that input is integer (as opposed to verifying that input has a letter). You never know what symbol may be typed. There are many symbols besides letters.
If id does not have many digits and can be placed to the integer data type you may want to do like this

```
long long id;
while (true) {
   cout << "Enter your ID: ";
   getline(cin, input);

   stringstream strm(input);
   if (strm >> id)
     break;
   cout << "ID has invalid symbols or too long" << endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i would use regular expressions for that kind of check. It works just like that:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>

std::string toTest("12345");
std::regex expr("^[\\d]+$");

if (std::regex_match(toTest, expr))
{
  // toTest contains only digits and at least one digit.
}
else
{
  // toString is either emtpy or contains non-digit characters
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Edit: If you want to modify your program to check if the id has a specific length you can use the following regular expressions:

```
std::regex expr4dig("^[\\d]{4}$");
```

This accepts 4 digits ids only.
If you want to check for a 4 to 8 digit id you use this regular expression:

```
std::regex expr4to8dig("^[\\d]{4,8}$");
```